# An example of URL which cannot be converted .toURI()?

Tags: java, url, uri

The javadoc for [`URL`'s `.toURI()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI--) mentions that it can throw a [`URISyntaxException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URISyntaxException.html) if:

> [...] this URL is not formatted strictly according to to RFC2396 and cannot be converted to a URI.

However, I have so far unsuccessfully tried to trigger this exception. What is more, you need to "pass" the `URL` constructor tests anyway.

So, does there exist an example of a valid `URL` which is not a valid `URI`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `URL` class is particularly forgiving when it comes to tolerating syntactically incorrect URLs. If I remember correctly, it only validates if there is a known protocol handler for the scheme and accepts everything in the scheme specific part.

The easiest way to produce a `URISyntaxException` is probably something like this:

```
new URL("http:// ").toURI();
```

Comment: Meh. I have actually never tried that! And yes, it indeed triggers that exception. Duh.

Comment: Note that it's not just about syntactically incorrect URLs. For example, `http://exámple.com/ /foo` is a valid URL (not a valid URI as per old RFCs though) which works with `java.net.URL` but breaks `java.net.URI`.

Answer (score 2):

It may contain any of the following characters:

```
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=.
```

Any other character needs to be encoded with the percent-encoding (%hh). Each part of the URI has further restrictions about what characters need to be represented by an percent-encoded word.

It is also true that different characters are legal at different points. For example, according to RFC 2396, an unescaped '?' is legal in the fragment part but not the path part.

Comment: That depends ;) All of this is defined in RFC 3986, but the URL RFCs are not as readable as the former...