# Can a Java resource URL be an invalid URI?

Tags: java, url, uri, classpath

Calling [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) in Java returns a `URL`.  And a Java `URL` can, in general, be an [invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384311/an-example-of-url-which-cannot-be-converted-touri) `URI`. By “invalid URI” I mean here being a URL that throws an `URISyntaxException` when calling [`toURI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#toURI()).

Are there some guarantees that this will not happen? That is: does the language guarantee that `getResource` will return a `URL` of the sort that can be converted to a `URI`? Otherwise, can anybody provide a – possibly hypothetical – example?

Answer (score 0):

As per the *JavaDoc*, it looks like it will be any *url* that is not in compliance to *[RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)*.

> *"... Note, any URL instance that complies with RFC 2396 can be converted to a URI. However, some URLs that are not strictly in compliance can not be converted to a URI. ..."*

Here is the RFC for a *url*, if you'd like to compare the grammar—section 2.
*[RFC 1738 – Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738)*.